# OpenOffice Calc macro to add pie chart

Tags: macros, charts, openoffice-calc, basic

I am trying to insert a piechart in open-office using macro. But the code shows error:

Line:

> `Dim oDiagram As New com.sun.star.chart.PieDiagram`

Error:

> `"Object not accessible. Invalid reference."`

I am unable to figure out why. Kindly help. Here is my complete macro code:

```basic
Sub Macro1

    Dim oRange as Object
    Dim oRangeAddress(1) As New com.sun.star.table.CellRangeAddress
    Dim oDiagram As New com.sun.star.chart.PieDiagram
    Dim oRect As New com.sun.star.awt.Rectangle
    Dim cTitle as String

    oRange = thisComponent.getCurrentSelection.getRangeAddress
    oSheets = ThisComponent.getSheets()
    oSheet = oSheets.getByIndex(0)
    oCharts = oSheet.Charts

    oRect.Width = 10000
    oRect.Height = 10000
    oRect.X = 8000
    oRect.Y = 1000

    oRangeAddress(0).Sheet = oRange.Sheet
    oRangeAddress(0).StartColumn = 0
    oRangeAddress(0).StartRow = 0
    oRangeAddress(0).EndColumn = 1
    oRangeAddress(0).EndRow = 2

    cTitle = "Test Results"
    oCharts.addNewByName(cTitle,oRect,oRangeAddress(),TRUE, TRUE)
    oChart = oCharts.getByName(cTitle).embeddedObject
    oChart.Diagram = oDiagram
    oChart.HasMainTitle = True
    oChart.Title.String = cTitle

End Sub
```

Here is the input sheet data:

[image: Input sheet data.]

Comment: AFAIK you can't instantiate a new diagram using `New com.sun.star.chart.PieDiagram`.  Instead, you could just use `Dim oChart as Object`. But now, `oCharts.getByName(cTitle).embeddedObject` throws a `NoSuchElementException` - i'm not sure why, same happens with [sample code from OOo Wiki](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/BASIC_Guide/Charts_in_Spreadsheets)... :-(

Comment: See https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=80494

Comment: Then how do I add pie chart ?

Comment: I've added an answer with an example working with OOo.Calc (but not with LIbreOffice).

Comment: In version 4.3.0, the issue [seems to be solved](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=80494#c6) - at least regarding the saple code from the OOo Wiki.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't instantiate a `com.sun.star.chart.PieDiagram` directly, independent of an already-existing chart. Instead, you'll have to create the chart first, and then create a `PieDiagram`. Thus, to make the macro work, do the following:

- remove the line `Dim oDiagram As New com.sun.star.chart.PieDiagram`
- change the line `oChart.Diagram = oDiagram` to `oChart.Diagram = oChart.createInstance("com.sun.star.chart.PieDiagram")`.

This results in the following code (i've tested this with OpenOffice.org Calc 4.1.0 on Win7):

```basic
Sub Macro1

    Dim oRange as Object
    Dim oRangeAddress(1) As New com.sun.star.table.CellRangeAddress
    Dim oRect As New com.sun.star.awt.Rectangle
    Dim cTitle as String

    oRange = thisComponent.getCurrentSelection.getRangeAddress
    oSheets = ThisComponent.getSheets()
    oSheet = oSheets.getByIndex(0)
    oCharts = oSheet.Charts

    oRect.Width = 10000
    oRect.Height = 10000
    oRect.X = 8000
    oRect.Y = 1000

    oRangeAddress(0).Sheet = oRange.Sheet
    oRangeAddress(0).StartColumn = 0
    oRangeAddress(0).StartRow = 0
    oRangeAddress(0).EndColumn = 1
    oRangeAddress(0).EndRow = 2

    cTitle = "Test Results"
    oCharts.addNewByName(cTitle,oRect,oRangeAddress(),TRUE, TRUE)
    oChart = oCharts.getByName(cTitle).embeddedObject
    oChart.Diagram = oChart.createInstance("com.sun.star.chart.PieDiagram")
    oChart.HasMainTitle = True
    oChart.Title.String = cTitle

End Sub
```

Running the macro should give the following result:

[image: Pie Chart created by Basic macro]

*NB: The macro **won't run on LibreOffice Calc**; it only works with OpenOffice.org Calc. I think this a LibreOffice bug, since i coudn't find any differences in the API of OOo and LO.*